# TYPO3: No preconfigured distributions

Tags: php, content-management-system, typo3

In a freshly installed TYPO3 7.6.14, after requesting preconfigured distributions during installation, none is available in the backend.  In fact, only installed extensions are displayed. The objective is to follow the Getting Started tutorial using the Introduction Package.  As a noob to TYPO3 I have no clue how best to proceed.

Installation is in Windows 10, running Apache 2.4, PHP 7.0, MySQL server 5.7. Clicking on "Get preconfigured distribution" yields a blank page, even after clicking on Show also not suitable. Clicking on Get Extensions also yields a blank display: "No data available in table"

Comment: A blank page always indicates an (PHP) error which is not shown. You can try to identify the error in your error-log, otherwise switch to develop mode in the install-tool, to get an error output instead of blank pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at all sure of how I got out of the hole I was in, but extensions & distributions are now available.  So the question is now moot.

Edit:
Installed TYPO3 on a Ubuntu VM and had the same issue - no extensions or preconfigured distributions even after it seemed like a long delay for downloading.  Cleared the cache and tried again - with success.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens, Switch to "get extensions" in top of the Extension Module anderen Update the List with the Button in the Top right Corner.
If this doesn't help: Clear the typo3temp folder anderen repeat the steps above.